# How to implement convolutions using DFT?

Tags: arrays, signal-processing, fft, convolution

So from my understanding it is possible to perform convolutions via the Discrete Fourier Transform. From what I read around the process simply involves mutliplying the DFT of both the kernel and the input. However, I am at a loss to understand how to implement the actual multiplication of the spectra as the DFT of two arrays of different sizes would be different.

So in psuedocode imagine I have an array `arr` of length 1024 and kernel `kern` of length 8.

To get the convolution of `arr` and `kern` I perform:

`IDFT(DFT(arr)*DFT(kern))`

However `DFT(arr)` is an array of length 1024 and `DFT(kern)` is an array of length 8. So how are they multiplied?

Comment: You just need to zero pad the smaller signal (kern) to the size of the larger signal.

Comment: @PaulR thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do a convolution with the DFT, the size of the DFT has to be at least as big as the convolution result -- your kernel size PLUS your input size.  You zero-pad them both out to this size, and then use the same size for both DFTs and the IDFT.

Note that this is *not efficient at all* if your kernel is much smaller than your input.  In this (the usual) case, you can use the overlap-add or overlap-save method to divide your input up into chunks that are about the same size as your kernel.

See, for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FPzZj30hPY4

This is *still* not efficient for really small kernels.  If your kernel is really only 8 samples long, then you shouldn't be bothering with any of this stuff.  The simple implementation will be faster.

Comment: So for the case of a 2D convolution I'd have to add that many rows and columns then zero pad. Also why can't one just zero pad till the kernel is the size of the larger input?

Comment: @ACCurrent Yes, for 2D you have to pad out in both dimensions.  You can do overlap-add in 2D as well.  You can't just pad up to the input size, because the output of the convolution needs to fit into the IDFT, and the output size is the sum of the input sizes.